# How to find the period of $\cos(\cos\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the period of $f(\theta)=\cos(\cos\theta)$?

For this, I've taken the easiest approach:

Let $T$ be the least positive value for which the function is positive.

Then $$f(\theta)= f(\theta + T) \\ \implies \cos(\cos\theta) = \cos(\cos(\theta +T)) \\ \implies \cos\theta = 2n\pi \underset{-}{+} \cos(\theta +T) $$. Now, what to do to find $T$?I , by inspection, found that $T = \pi$ . But I want to deduce it analytically as above. Can anyone tell me how to proceed then??

## Edit :

The period is not at all $2\pi$.

Here is the graph plotted by [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=1f7f038e713da9929b0f9a3ce48f97cd&title=Math+Help+Boards:+Graph+Plotter&theme=blue):

[graph http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP32721f0cbh3118g17a0600001c07a42c8425h5b1?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=25&w=300.&h=196.&cdf=RangeControl](http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP32721f0cbh3118g17a0600001c07a42c8425h5b1?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=25&w=300.&h=196.&cdf=RangeControl)

Comment: yes you would see that $\cos(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta+T)$ are both elements of $[-1,1]$ so how could they differe by $2n\pi$ if $n\neq 0$?

Comment: Notice that $\cos(\cos(\theta))=\cos(|\cos(\theta)|)$. The minimal positive period of $\cos(\theta)$ is $2\pi$ and for $|\cos(\theta)|$ it is $\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos\cos\theta=1\iff\frac{\cos\theta}{2\pi}\in\Bbb Z\iff\cos\theta=0\iff\frac{\theta-\frac\pi2}{\pi}\in\Bbb Z$$

That is, $\cos\cos\theta$ reach its maximum only for $\theta\equiv\pi/2\pmod\pi$.

Moreover, $\cos\cos\theta=\cos\cos(\theta+\pi)$ for any $\theta\in\Bbb R$. Thus, the period is $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks; I thought I just saw $2\pi$ in place of $\pi$ in the last line; sorry. However, can't I prove it in the way I was going as above?

Comment: I've some problem in conceiving your argument; could you tell why you showed for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\cos(\cos\theta)$ is max?? I am not understanding why you did this especially the steps $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{2\pi}\in\Bbb Z$ & $\dfrac{\theta-\frac\pi2}{\pi}\in\Bbb Z$. Mean to ask how your first argument is related to the argument in the last line; you've found for what angle the function is max; then you wrote $\cos\cos\theta=\cos\cos(\theta+\pi)$; how are they related with each other?? I'm not getting:( Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

A picture might be worth 1000 words. As $\theta$ traverses either the upper half of the circle or the lower half, we can see $\cos(\cos(\theta))$ complete a full period.

[image]